# Lua - too many captures. How fix it?

Tags: lua

Have problems with this one. If try convert cirilic words or wors have to many symbols and have error

[image: 1]

```lua
function to_string(t)
    local o = {};
    for _, v in ipairs(t) do
        local b = v < 0 and (0xff + v + 1) or v;
        table.insert(o, string.char(b));
    end
    return table.concat(o);
end
function to_bytes(s)
    local c = { s:match( (s:gsub(".", "(.)")) ) };
    local o = {};
    for _, v in pairs(c) do
        table.insert(o, v:byte());
    end
    return o;
end
local t = to_bytes("If this have to many words или русские");
local out = "\\"
local chars = #t;
for i = 1, chars do
    out = out..tostring(t[i]);
    if i < chars then
        out = out.."\\"
    end
end
out = out..""
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is self-explanatory: you have too many captures in your pattern (those groups that are wrapped into parentheses). The default value is 32. You have a couple of options: (1) recompile your Lua version to use a large number (you'll have to modify `LUA_MAXCAPTURES` value), but keep in mind that this limit is there for a reason and (2) change your pattern to avoid this many captures (possibly splitting into smaller fragments/patterns). You may also consider using more powerful parsers, like [LPEG](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/%7Eroberto/lpeg/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex to convert string to array of bytes

```
function to_bytes(s)
    return {s:byte(1, -1)}
end
```